# Unexpected Location of Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly When NUnit Runs Multiple Assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection, nunit

I recently encountered an odd issue when performing unit tests. My solution contains a helper class with a property for getting the directory of the executing assembly. It looks like this:

```cs
public static class DirectoryHelper
{
    public static string ExecutingAssemblyDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            var codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            var uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called through various test classes to get relative file paths to dependent resources.

Take the following contrived projects as examples:

**TestProject1.dll - TestFixture1.cs**

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture1
{
    [Test]
    public void VerifyExecutingAssemblyDirectory1()
    {
        StringAssert.Contains(@"\TestProject1\bin\Debug", 
        DirectoryHelper.ExecutingAssemblyDirectory);
    }
}
```

**TestProject2.dll - TestFixture2.cs**

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture2
{
    [Test]
    public void VerifyExecutingAssemblyDirectory1()
    {
        StringAssert.Contains(@"TestProject2\bin\Debug", 
        DirectoryHelper.ExecutingAssemblyDirectory);
    }
}
```

When these tests are ran individually they pass and the location of the returned assembly is the debug folder of the test class.

However, when ran together, TestFixture2.VerifyExecutingAssemblyDirectory2() is actually returning the path to the bin folder of `TestProject1`, rather than `TestProject2`.

**I'm trying to determine why this behavior is happening and understand a better way of going about this.** 
I've found that using `.GetCallingAssembly` will resolve this problem, but it doesn't seem like I should have to do this.

I've created an example to reproduce this issue and posted to GitHub. [TylerNielsen/NUnitExecutingAssemblyExample](https://github.com/TylerNielsen/NUnitExecutingAssemblyExample)

Note: I'm aware of the `TestContext.TestDirectory` in NUnit, however this library is currently not dependent on NUnit and I'd prefer to keep it that way.

**UPDATE**
I'm running the NUnit tests through both Resharper in Visual Studio and via NUnit3-Console. When I run using NUnit3-Console, I'm only specifying the two individual .dlls and not providing any other arguments.

Comment: Have you already considered [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/06/26/assembly-codebase-vs-assembly-location/)?

Comment: @dymanoid - Location won't work for this unfortunately because some apps may make shadow copies of the .dll. For example, the experimental NUnit GUI does this and break relative references since only the DLL is copied. Code base ensures it still references where the dll source was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both TestProject1 and TestProject2 reference the assembly containing DirectoryHelper. I'm assuming that your references cause the assembly to be copied to the individual (separate) output directories.

When you run both test assemblies together, one of them causes it's "personal" copy of that assembly to be loaded. The second one finds that the assembly is already in memory.

Of course, this behavior will depend on how you run the assemblies, which you haven't said. In the case where you use nunit3-console, it will also depend on your command-line arguments, especially whether you use a separate process for each assembly.

Comment: I'm running into this while running tests in both Visual Studio and the nunit3-console. When using the console, I'm not providing any arguments other than the two test .dlls

Comment: So since the assembly is already loaded in memory from the location of the .dll that executed in NUnit first, the way around this would be that I need to use .GetCallingAssembly or TestContext.TestDirectory to make sure I'm getting the correct location? Or is there any other way to resolve this through NUnit settings?

Comment: That's my hypothesis. You'd have to verify it by running the code in diffeent ways, and different orders.

Comment: Do you reallly care which copy is loaded? What's the purpose of the test? Why does it matter to you that a certain directory was used? If you actually have a reason why that's important, perhaps that's what you should be asking about.

Comment: Mentioned that in my original post - it matters if using this to create relative file paths. If the project being ran includes a file that's included in the build, then it's important to have the right assembly or the file might not be found.

Comment: In that case, you may be better off using a common output directory, rather than two separate directories.